# What is the purpose of [ng\:cloak] [ng-cloak] selectors (Contained in Spring Boot Security Tutorial)?

Tags: css, angularjs, spring-security, spring-boot

I'm going through a spring boot tutorial and it contains an example with the following css:

```
    <style type="text/css">
    [ng\:cloak], [ng-cloak], .ng-cloak {
      display: none !important;
    }
    </style>
    </head>

    <body ng-app="hello">
      <div class="container">
        <h1>Greeting</h1>
        <div ng-controller="home" ng-cloak class="ng-cloak">
```

I undestand what the cloak class is for.  I'm just wondering what the purpose of the first two strange looking selectors is?

TIA,
Ole

Comment: They are attribute selectors. just meaning the css is looking for atribute names (directives also) instead of only classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From angular [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak):

> The ngCloak directive is used to prevent the Angular html template from being briefly displayed by the browser in its raw (uncompiled) form while your application is loading. Use this directive to avoid the undesirable flicker effect caused by the html template display.

It is done by adding the css rule that you mentioned to the page, where `[ng-cloak]` - is an [attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) that matches the elements by attribute rather than class, id, or element name:

```
<div ng-cloak>...</div>
```

**EDIT**:

Which selector to use in the css rule depends on which syntax you use in html markup. The same directive may be triggered the different ways - by element name, class name or attribute name. You could enable this directive this way `<div ng:cloak></div>`. Then it would be sufficient to have the `[ng\:cloak]` selector only in your css.

**The purpose of the `ngCloak` directive is to remove the `ng-cloak` class and attributes (and thus make the element visible) once complation is over**.

Comment: Would it still work if for example the class="ng-cloak" was left off?  Also the selector [ng\:cloak] does not look like it's used at all .... ?

Comment: @Ole, I added the answer to your question to the post.

Comment: thanks - I'm still a puzzled WRT to the :cloak pseudo selector ... it does not appear to be a real css pseudo selector ... like a:visited ... so how does it work?  Do CSS engines of browsers just automatically trigger on custom pseudo selectors like ng:cloak?